# Centering a large rectangle inside a grid which dimensions are smaller (and ClipToBounds doesn't work)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to position a rectangle in the center of a grid with a restricted height, like so:

```
<Grid ClipToBounds="False">
    <Grid Background="LightBlue" Height="10" ClipToBounds="False" Margin="0,27,0,79">
        <Rectangle Height="40" Width="20" Fill="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ClipToBounds="False"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I've expected it to look like that:

[image]

But instead it looks like that:

[image]

I know the my child rectangle is bigger and it is understandable that it clips, however, my ClipToBounds have no effect of anything. After reading around, I found that indeed [Grid does not respect "ClipToBounds"](http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/12/28/cliptoboundsmaybe/).

I tried to use Canvas, as suggested in the [aforementioned article](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7KVe.png) by Dr.Wpf but I can't seem to get it right.

Is there anything I can do to make it look like the 1st picture, without resorting to C# code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a little hard to tell exactly what your requirements are here. You said you tried it witha  Canvas, but you can't seem to get it right. What didn't work?

I used this code:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="TestApp.MainWindow"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="175" Height="170" Background="LightGray">

    <Grid>
        <Canvas Background="LightBlue" Height="10" 
                Margin="0,27,0,79" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Rectangle Height="40" Width="20" Fill="Black" 
                       Canvas.Left="66" Canvas.Top="-15" />
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

and was able to essentially fake what your screenshot looked like. But (as you can tell by the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` parts of my code) it is sort of hackish. You could get rid of the `Canvas.Left` by binding to the `ActualWidth` of the `Canvas` and using an `IValueConverter` that converts it to the correct value.

**Edit:**

After a little further exploration, I came up with a slightly less hackish way of doing it. Though the nesting kind of makes me cringe, the only thing hardcoded is the top margin to get it centered vertically. Again, that can be done with an `IValueConverter`, but you don't want that. I'm not sure I can get any better than this, unfortunately.

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="WpfApplication10.MainWindow"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="640" Height="480">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid Background="LightBlue" Height="10" ClipToBounds="False" Margin="0,27,0,79">        
            <Canvas>
                <Grid Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Canvas}}"
                      Height="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Canvas}}">
                    <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 -40 0 0">
                        <Rectangle Height="40" Width="20" Fill="Black" ClipToBounds="False"/>           
                    </Canvas>
                </Grid>
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: What I was trying to do is to make the rectangle's center to appear in the center of the parent grid AND to disregard the borders of the grid by overflowing above its borders. Your solution is way too hardcoded for my needs. I *COULD* use a converter like you say, however, but I'd much rather have a XAML-only solution if possible (but without hardcoding the values).

Comment: @VitalyB - understood. I tried one more time. Still has one value hardcoded, but I got rid of the other one. See my edit. Still probably won't work for you, but just trying to see what I can come up with.

Comment: Nice solution! :). Marked as answer. You're right, it isn't very pretty and quite on the hackish side and I guess in this case it is better to use a converter, but question-wise, it is a legitimate answer and the hardcoded parts are very minimal. Thanks!